# Is there a jQuery jEditable Multi-select plugin?

Tags: jquery, select, plugins, jeditable, multi-select

I'm using the excellent [jEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) plugin for some in-place editing on my page. There is one spot I need a multiple select element. Is there a jEditable plugin that allows me to do this?

I've been trying to use the [jEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) author's plugin API to create my own multiselect plugin, but no dice so far. There just doesn't seem to be quite enough documentation on what each function does in the API. And every single example plugin he provides appears to rely on other jQuery plugins. I just need a basic multiple select element...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a small patch to Kalyan's suggestion that caused it not to work without the optional "selected" option, and unhardcoded the size attribute.  Then I modified it to be a jEditable plugin rather than something you have to paste into jEditable itself.  I'm currently using this on a customer website, though I use it exclusively populated by a json string so other methods may still be buggy.

```
$.editable.addInputType("multiselect", {
    element: function (settings, original) {
        var select = $('<select multiple="multiple" />');

        if (settings.width != 'none') { select.width(settings.width); }
        if (settings.size) { select.attr('size', settings.size); }

        $(this).append(select);
        return (select);
    },
    content: function (data, settings, original) {
        /* If it is string assume it is json. */
        if (String == data.constructor) {
            eval('var json = ' + data);
        } else {
            /* Otherwise assume it is a hash already. */
            var json = data;
        }
        for (var key in json) {
            if (!json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                continue;
            }
            if ('selected' == key) {
                continue;
            }
            var option = $('<option />').val(key).append(json[key]);
            $('select', this).append(option);
        }

        if ($(this).val() == json['selected'] ||
                            $(this).html() == $.trim(original.revert)) {
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        }

        /* Loop option again to set selected. IE needed this... */
        $('select', this).children().each(function () {
            if (json.selected) {
                var option = $(this);
                $.each(json.selected, function (index, value) {
                    if (option.val() == value) {
                        option.attr('selected', 'selected');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                if (original.revert.indexOf($(this).html()) != -1)
                    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, it shows a select that allows to choose multiple options, but I can't get it to show the selected options in the cell. It just one option if my sUpdateURL function returns a valid value or crashes if it isn't a valid value :(

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for the same as well. Trying to achieve that, but nothing seems to work.

By the way, I found this but this doesnt seem to work either - http://pastebin.com/cbDndv5h

Comment: Your pastebin example needed just a little refinement.  I updated it in my answer and it works well for me.

Answer (score -1):

The jeditable plugin do this.
Example:

```
$('.editable').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', { 
 data   : " {'E':'Letter E','F':'Letter F','G':'Letter G', 'selected':'F'}",
 type   : 'select',
 submit : 'OK'
});
```

Comment: No, this is not a multiple select, it only allows to select one item.