# Multiple Select type for Jeditable - In Place Editor plugin

Tags: jquery, select, jeditable

I use jeditable in my project where I dynamically update lots of different types of content: text, textarea and select.

I would need a new type to meet one of my needs : a multi-select type that could be called "selectmulti".

When editing the field typed "selectmulti", a select list appears and would allow users to select multiple choices. Saving would return an array and update.php will store this array in my DB.

Ex:

```
<div class='border'>
  <span class='title'>Language: </span>
  <span class='editableLang' id='contact_language'>
    ".$row['contact_language']."
  </span>
</div>
```

And the Javascript function:

```
    $('.editableLang').editable('update.php', { 
        data        : '<?php print json_encode($tab_lang); ?>',
        id          : 'cellid',
        name        : 'cellvalue',
        event       : 'dblclick',
        tooltip     : 'Double click to edit...',
        submitdata  : {id: "<?php echo $id_contact; ?>"},
        type        : 'selectmulti',
        style       : 'display: inline',
        submit      : 'Save',
        cancel      : 'Cancel'
     });
```

I just can't figure out how to get the different values in an array (in my case 'cellvalue' would be the array) and save it in the DB.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated !

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone interested, my solution is on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ixuye4/edit

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597756/is-there-a-jquery-jeditable-multi-select-plugin

Answer (score 3):

just one correction. This works, but - obviously - you have to use "multiselect" as value of the param "type", when you call editable, not "select":

```
$('.editable').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', { 
 data   : " {'E':'Letter E','F':'Letter F','G':'Letter G', 'selected':'F'}",
 type   : 'multiselect',
 submit : 'OK'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me!

```
$.editable.addInputType("multiselect", {
    element: function (settings, original) {
        var select = $('<select multiple="multiple" />');

        if (settings.width != 'none') { select.width(settings.width); }
        if (settings.size) { select.attr('size', settings.size); }

        $(this).append(select);
        return (select);
    },
    content: function (data, settings, original) {
        /* If it is string assume it is json. */
        if (String == data.constructor) {
            eval('var json = ' + data);
        } else {
            /* Otherwise assume it is a hash already. */
            var json = data;
        }
        for (var key in json) {
            if (!json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                continue;
            }
            if ('selected' == key) {
                continue;
            }
            var option = $('<option />').val(key).append(json[key]);
            $('select', this).append(option);
        }

        if ($(this).val() == json['selected'] ||
                            $(this).html() == $.trim(original.revert)) {
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        }

        /* Loop option again to set selected. IE needed this... */
        $('select', this).children().each(function () {
            if (json.selected) {
                var option = $(this);
                $.each(json.selected, function (index, value) {
                    if (option.val() == value) {
                        option.attr('selected', 'selected');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                if (original.revert.indexOf($(this).html()) != -1)
                    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
            }
        });
    }
});

$('.editable').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', { 
 data   : " {'E':'Letter E','F':'Letter F','G':'Letter G', 'selected':'F'}",
 type   : 'select',
 submit : 'OK'
});
```

http://pastebin.com/tZwHMHQD

Comment: You should put the code here rather than just placing a link to pastebin, otherwise your answer could suffer from linkrot.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone happens to be looking for a quick and dirty solution:

```
$.editable.addInputType('multi', {
    element : function(settings, original) {
        var select = $('<select multiple="multiple" />');

        if (settings.width != 'none') { select.width(settings.width); }
        if (settings.size) { select.attr('size', settings.size); }

        $(this).append(select);
        return (select);
    },
    content: function (data, settings, original) {

        /* If it is string assume it is json. */
        if (String == data.constructor) {
            eval('var json = ' + data);
        } else {
            /* Otherwise assume it is a hash already. */
            var json = data;
        }

        for (var key in json) {

            if (!json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                continue;
            }
            if ('selected' == key) {
                continue;
            }
            var option = $('<option />').val(key).append(json[key]);
            $('select', this).append(option);

        }

    }
});
```